# Dont send to sql spaces

Tags: php, sql, space

Block spaces in textbox and dont send sql, i need trim or something.

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<=count($varray)-1;$i++) {
echo "<tr><th>Village name</th><td><input tabindex=\"6\" type=\"text\" name=\"dname$i\" 
value=\"".$varray[$i]['name']."\" maxlength=\"30\" class=\"text\"></td></tr>";
}
?>
```

I think i must add there (its .tpl). And i want to add codes there who want help me. But if this is wrong code please tell me Sorry for my bad English. Thank for help...

Comment: You might need to add some example of what you currently have and what you want to have, because honestly, I don't really know what you are even trying to do...

Comment: have you tried [**RTRIM**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx) in SQL Server or [**Trim**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) in MySql?

Answer (score 2):

Use preg_replace to strips excess whitespace from a string

```
 preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str)
```

[for more info](https://www.php.net/preg_replace)

Comment: please explain what you want exactly? Put your snippet here so that i can help you

Comment: `$str = 'foo   o';
$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str);
// This will be 'foo o' now
echo $str'` and if you want to remove completely then`$str = 'foo   o';
$str = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $str);
// This will be 'fooo' now
echo $str;`

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to send any spaces at all? Sounds like a job for [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Just do something like

```
$to_database = str_replace(' ','',$input);
```